# How to correctly save entity with @ManyToMany in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I know how to persist entity with @ManyToMany relation in pure Hibernate. But how to do it correctly in Spring?

In hibernate that would be:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction.begin();

Book book = new Book("title", "isbn");
Category category = new Category("horror");

category.addBook(book);

em.persist(book);

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.getTransaction().close();
```

something like this. But what about Spring, let's say that I have `@Service` which receive Book or BookDto from @RestController.

```
public void saveBook(Book book) {
    //what now
}
```

What I should do here, is `bookRepository.save(book);` would be enough to save this @ManyToMany relation? Don't I need additional methods like addBook, addCategory, removeBook etc.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

Answer (score 2):

Spring's repository is doing nothing than just wrapping entityManager and executing it's persist method. You can have a look at [default implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L578)

That's why whatever possible in "pure hibernate" is possible with spring's repositories with a couple of notes

**Note 1** With spring you most probably will replace transaction boiler-plate with `@Transactional` annotations, that's why you need to be careful about entities passed between methods.

**Note 2** The code you referred as "pure hibernate" is actually "pure JPA", there was no hibernate mentioned. Probably hibernate was your JPA implementation.

Comment: So do I have to write this in my JPQL query or I can just leave it as it is? Note 1: yup I know that, Note 2: excuse me for not being technically precise :P

Comment: For the example you mentioned *bookRepository.save* will do exactly the same stuff. Otherwise you can always inject entityManager into your repository and do some custom logic if default doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The standard recipe to handle state management of your entities with the use of Spring Boot is:

1. Create entity classess annotated with @Entity (which you have already done, I presume) - for example a Book.class entity;
2. Create repository interface that extends JPARepository<T,ID>, where T is your entity class (create one for Book and another one for Category), and ID is the Primary Key of your entity class. This will give you the advantage of having a default implementation of many useful repository methods, like save(), findOneById(), etc;

```
public interface BookRepository extends JPARepository<Book, Long> {}
```

assuming that you have set Long as a primary key of your book entity;

3. Inject the repository in the service class;
4. Now you can use your service class and method like so:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class BookService {

private final BookRepository bookRepository;

@Transactional
public void saveBook() {

   // just copying the logic from your question
   // but normally You would pass it as an argument to the method
    Book book = new Book("title", "isbn");
    Category category = new Category("horror");
    category.addBook(book);
    bookRepository.save(book);

    }
}
```

Answering Your 2nd question - yes, you have to take care of keeping both entities relationships in sync, there is no get-away from that here. So in @ManyToMany relationship, you have to add category to book categories collection and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! I have already done it like this yesterday but this is good answer and it should be there for future questions like this. Cheers!